# Neural Network - Keras - keyError: 'acc'

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, matplotlib, keras

I am learning Keras through udemy.

i got this error although i have written code as same as the instructor did.

In the last part I get this error:

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XbtI.png)

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

This is part of my code:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import Adam 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

n_pts = 500
np.random.seed(0)
Xa = np.array([np.random.normal(13, 2, n_pts),
           np.random.normal(12, 2, n_pts)]).T
Xb = np.array([np.random.normal(8, 2, n_pts),
           np.random.normal(6, 2, n_pts)]).T



X = np.vstack((Xa, Xb)) 
y = np.matrix(np.append(np.zeros(n_pts), np.ones(n_pts))).T

plt.scatter(X[:n_pts,0], X[:n_pts,1])
plt.scatter(X[n_pts:,0], X[n_pts:,1  ])


model =Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=1,input_shape=(2,),activation='sigmoid'))   
adam = Adam(lr=0.1)
model.compile(adam , loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])  
h=model.fit(x=X, y=y, verbose=1,batch_size=50,epochs=500,shuffle='true')


plt.plot(h.history['acc'])
plt.title('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['accuracy'])
```

Comment: what does h.history.keys() return?

Comment: it is returning- dict_keys(['loss', 'accuracy'])

Comment: so h.history['accuracy'] and not h.history['acc']

Comment: thanks sir it's working..

Answer (score 0):

In tf 2.0, you have to use the full word `accuracy` instead of `acc` as was in tf 1.x. Even though you are not using

> import from tensorflow.keras xyz